# flashVars flex3

Tags: apache-flex, flashvars

hi im trying to using flashVars however for some reason there not getting sent to my flex app.

Im embedding my object in a velocity file and here is the object embed code;

```
<object width="$!WIDTH" height="$!HEIGHT">
    <param name="flashVars" value="maximizeUrl=http://maximizeUrl"/>       
    <param name="movie" value="$!SRC"/>
    <embed src="$!SRC" width="$!WIDTH" height="$!HEIGHT"/>
</object>
```

any ideas why this is not happening for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're having problems with Firefox, which ignores the object tag, and uses the embed tag instead.  You need to add the flashvars parameter as an attribute there as well:

```
<object width="$!WIDTH" height="$!HEIGHT">
        <param name="flashVars" value="maximizeUrl=http://maximizeUrl"/>       
    <param name="movie" value="$!SRC"/>
    <embed src="$!SRC" width="$!WIDTH" height="$!HEIGHT" flashVars="maximizeUrl=http://maximizeUrl"/>
</object>
```

Alternatively, you could use [SWFObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) to dynamically generate the embedding code.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the answer from David, use SWFObject or prefreably use the code that comes with flexbuilder. check out my answer for this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452402/how-to-make-javascript-talk-to-flash-ac3-embedded-with-swfobject-2-0#461727